# Parallel nested for loop in bash

Tags: bash, nested-loops

I am trying to run a c executable through bash. The executable will take a different argument in each iteration, and I want to do it in parallel since I have 12 cores available.

I tried

```
w=1;
for i in {1..100}
do
l=$(($i-1));
for j in {12*l..12*i}
do
./run $w/100 > "$w"_out &
done
expr=$w % 12;
if ["$expr" -eq "0"]
then wait;
fi;
done
```

run is the c executable. I want to run it with increasing argument w in each step, and I want to wait until all processes are done if 12 of the cores are in use. SO basically, I will run 12 executables at the same time, then wait until they are completed, and then move to the next 12.

Hope I made my point clear.

Cheers.

Comment: Is that `{12*l..12*i}` supposed to do arithmetic?  A multiplication?  You are not using that `j` in the loop.  Is that intended?  Is the `$W % 12` supposed to perform math as well?  Are you interested in error handling of all the different calls as well?

Comment: Are you aware that your variable `w` is never changed?  It is just set to `1` in the beginning, and that's it.

Comment: Using `expr` as a variable name is likely to cause grief at some point... Some code indenting/formatting might make things a bit easier to understand. Add a `set -x` before your loop(s) to see exactly what is being run...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [gnu parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) instead:

```
parallel ./myscript {1} ::: {1..100}
```

You can specify the number of parallel processes with the `-P` option, but it defaults to the number of cores in the system.

You can also specify `-k` to keep the output order and redirect the file.

To redirect the output to individual files, you can specify the output redirection, but you have to quote it, so that it is not parsed by the shell. For example:

```
parallel ./run {1} '>' {1}_out ::: {1..10}
```

is equivalent to running `./run 1 > 1_out` to `./run 10 > 10_out`

Comment: Thank you. But, could you please be more specific? I am having quite hard times to learn parallel.

From shell, I call ./run 1 > 1_out
and I will increase 1's to some number. My outputs will be like 
1_out, 2_out, 3_out (for 1,2,3)

Comment: You can do that by quoting the redirection character. See edit for an example.

Comment: @user178882 see if `man parallel_tutorial` helps you learn GNU Parallel.

Comment: Verify if your parallel version is correct. On Ubuntu 20, I already had a parallel executable installed, but it wasn't supporting the syntax above. Had to install the required executable seperately.